# Не функционирует JS при загрузке контента через ajax.

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, dom

Здравствуйте, есть функция которая подгружает ajax контент, но в загружаемом контенте на работают jQuery плагины, Может кто поправить?

Версия jQuery 1.9.1

```
;(function($, undefined) {

    $(document).on('click', '[data-trigger="ajax"]', function() {
        var $this = $(this)
            ,data = $this.data()
            ,$target
            ,spinner
            ;
        if (typeof data['target'] != 'undefined') {
            $target = $(data['target']);
            if (typeof Spinner == 'function') {
                spinner = new Spinner({color: '#3d9bce'}).spin($target[0]);
            }
            $target.load($this.attr('href'), function() {
                if (spinner) {
                    spinner.stop();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: это в принципе плохая идея загружать скрипты через load вместе html.

Comment: Я наверное не правильно выразился, Загружается страница, со всеми js плагинами, и по ajax ссылке загружаю контент в определенное место, и те плагины которые загрузились изначально не владеют теми элементами которые загрузились через ajax

Comment: Может кто альтернативу посоветует?

Строю Админ панель на ajax, для этого использую плагин pjax, но и в нем при загрузке ajax контента не работает javascript, что за беда такая?

Comment: что значит не владеют ? естественно к новым добавленным элементам не будут применены плагины. максимум что можно - только события через on()

Comment: Интересное явление, вот так заработал Датапикер при подгрузке, 

      $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).live('mouseover', function() { $(this).datepicker() });
    });  
  
соответственно если расставить всем обработчик live, то они будут работать, но должно же быть решение без такого кастыля? : )